# ¿Cómo mostrar clientes y pedidos de un negocio en un dashboard?

Tags: php, mysqli

Necesito que cuando el negocio ingrese a tal pagina le muestre cuantos clientes tiene y cuantos pedidos tiene su negocio, no estoy logrando mostrarlo. Hice esto, el error de este código esta en el where que para que me muestre el detalle de un negocio le tengo que pasar el id, y deberia tomarlo de la vista automaticamente agradezco su ayuda

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "entorno1", "Entorno.3030", "habitue");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  die("Conexión fallida:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//$sql = "SELECT COUNT(cliente_id) as total, cliente_id FROM cliente_negocio GROUP BY(cliente_id) WHERE negocio_id=9";
                                
$sql = "SELECT count(cliente_id) as total FROM cliente_negocio WHERE negocio_id= 9";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
echo "<div>";
 while ($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
   echo "<br>";
   echo "<div>";
   echo "<h2 >".$a['total']."</h2>";
   echo "</div>";
 }
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: Que error tiene este código?, Por favor lee [ask], por cierto no coloques etiquetas que no son relevantes a la pregunta (aquí no hay nada de Laravel)

Comment: el erro esta en el where que para que me muestre el detalle de un negocio le tengo que pasar el id , y deberia tomarlo de la vista automaticamente

Comment: Pues si quieres que sea automático, lee la variable donde almacenas el ID y pásalo a tu consulta

Comment: dentro de un where se puede meter una variable que contenga el id del negocio?

Comment: Si, concatenas la variable